# Pandas GroupBy aggegate only some groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a large dataframe where each key is assigned one value. However I do have cases where a key has multiple values, these need to be resolved by selecting a maximum value

An Example (date+test is the key):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1/1/16','1/2/16','1/1/16','1/1/16'],'test':['A','A','B','B'],'Val':[3,4,1,4]})
grouped = df.groupby(['date','test'])
```

I can do:

```
agg = grouped.apply(lambda x: x[x['Val'] == x['Val'].max()])
```

However df is ~400K entries, with only ~300 keys mapping to several values. I was hoping to speed up this process by separating offending keys from the rest and running max on the much small set and then recombine.

I can get count:

```
ct = grouped.count()
```

but how do I use it to index into the group?

this does NOT work:

```
grouped[ct>1]
```

thank you

[update 1]

Here is what I'm thinking.

```
keys = ['date','test']
ct = pd.DataFrame()
ct['Count'] = grouped.apply(lambda x: len(x))
ct.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = pd.merge(df,ct,on=keys,how='inner')
```

Now I can split data frame into two based on the count being 1 or greater.
Still would be happy to hear suggestion on how do it better.

Comment: is `grouped['Val'].idxmax()` what you're after?

Comment: Not exactly. I've come up with solution and updated my post. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['Max_Val'] = df.groupby(['date','test']).transform(lambda x: x.max() if x.size > 1 else x)
```

yields:

```
   Val    date test  Max_Val
0    3  1/1/16    A        3
1    4  1/2/16    A        4
2    1  1/1/16    B        4
3    4  1/1/16    B        4
```

Is this the result you're after?